# Docker fails on a fresh install with linux-ck-skylake kernel

Tags: arch-linux, docker

I am using a fresh install of the newest version of Docker on a freshly updated Arch Linux with linux-ck-skylake kernel version 5.12.2-1 but docker fails to run the hello-world image with the error:

```
$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: process_linux.go:458: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: can't load program: invalid argument: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

### docker info

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-tp-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 7
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 7
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 20.10.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8c906ff108ac28da23f69cc7b74f8e7a470d1df0.m
 runc version: 12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.12.2-1-ck-skylake
 Operating System: Arch Linux
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.42GiB
 Name: konradspc
 ID: 6NFV:RQP7:V6XK:7D6Z:W2LC:LPGR:HQBQ:V55P:BECL:WXPP:YPC5:2QQ2
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

The user is a member of the docker group.

How can I fix this error?

Update: I switched to the generic Kernel as the Linux CK kernel was not worth it to me anymore due to problems such as this one.

Comment: Was the kernel updated after installing Docker?

Comment: @muru: I tried every combination. First, I installed Docker, then when it didn't work I upgraded the packages including the kernel. Then when it still didn't work I removed Docker and reinstalled it.

Comment: Did you restart after upgrading the kernel?

Comment: @muru: Yes, I restarted multiple times. Could it be a problem with the linux-ck kernel? I found people with similar problems on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111715&p=149 but there is no solution stated. I updated the title to include this potentially relevant information.